# Is it Legal to Remove Magento Logo and Trademarks from Admin

Tags: magento, licensing, magento-1.4

I am working for a client he is requiring to remove Magento Logo and Trademarks from Magento Admin Backend i just want to Confirm is it Legal to remove or Hide.

Response Required ASAP

Comment: If you require a rock-solid response ASAP you should consider asking this the vendor. [Magneto offers paid support](http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/overview) which should be able to answer your question. The community edition is relased under OSL 3.0, a comment on the license is available [here](http://rosenlaw.com/OSL3.0-explained.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to RoyRubin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/44238/), a Magento Team member it looks like that there is no need for you to keep the logo in the templates of the [Community Edition](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/community-edition):

> The license does not require attribution on the templates. You should be fine to remove them and keep all copyright notices in the files.

You should keep the copyright notices inside the source-code files intact however. Please read the [OSL 3.0](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0) license to learn more about your rights with the software.

Comment: @AliNasrullah: OSL by itself requires that you attribute to any user of the derivate you produce that the software he/she is currently using (e.g. browsing) is running under OSL (that notice must be visible). Next to that you need to give access to the source-code of the application to any user the work is communicated to (explicitly for network use).